# How can I get to see table cell borders if border-collapse: separate?

Tags: css

This doesn't seem to show borders, although that's supposed to be the only reason for the CSS property `border-collapse`:

http://jsfiddle.net/pz6azgj8/

Did I make some mistake here? Or isn't this but not implemented in current browsers (FF35/IE11)?

[image: jsFiddle screenshot]

Comment: `tr` isn't a valid target for your border declaration.  Try doing it on `td` or on `table`

Comment: Where in the CSS3 spec is `tr` supposed to be an invalid element? I can't find that statement there.

Comment: The problem isn't the CSS3 spec.  `border-collapse` is part of the CSS2.1&2 specs.  The problem is that when you set the `border-collapse` to `separate`, you're changing the border rendering mode, which changes which elements are valid to receive a border.  In the border rendering mode you've triggered (and the default mode, btw), you're saying that a `tr` is not valid to receive a border, as a `tr` has no border rather than to space the rows/cells via `border-spacing` ... hence the `border-collapse: separate`.  Make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html

states this:

> **17.6 Borders**
>   [...]
>   **'border-collapse'**
>   Value:      collapse | separate | inherit
>   Initial:    separate
>   [...] The value 'separate' selects the separated borders border model. The value 'collapse' selects the collapsing borders model. [...]
>
> **17.6.1 The separated borders model**
>  
>   [...] Rows, columns, row groups, and column groups cannot have borders (i.e., user agents must ignore the border properties for those elements). [...]
>
> **17.6.2 The collapsing border model**
>   In the collapsing border model, it is possible to specify borders that surround all or part of a cell, row, row group, column, and column group.

You say

> This doesn't seem to show borders, although that's supposed to be the only reason for the CSS property `border-collapse`

It probably is indeed one reason for the existence of that property to allow borders for `<tr>`s - but the other way around: `separated` is the default-value and `collapse` allows you to create those borders around table-rows.

Comment: Might as well also add into this an answer for the question in the title -- How can I see the table cell borders if border collapse is separate? -- which is to apply the border to the `td` elements.

Answer (score -2):

Do border-collapse:collapse on the table CSS, it fixes it.

Comment: I know, but I'm wondering why the borders disappear if `border-collapse: separate` is set. I can't see a reason for this happening. I actually want the border to be separated.